# In Windows xp, how can I make the mouse cursor move off one edge of the screen onto the other?

Tags: windows-xp, mouse

It'd be useful if I could make the mouse cursor so that when the mouse cursor is for example near the right of the screen.. and I want it at the far left of the screen.. it'd be useful if I could just move it off the right of the screen and have it emerge from the left of the screen.

Or if the cursor is near the top of the screen it'd be good to be able to move it up a bit, off the top edge of the screen, and have it emerge from the bottom edge of the screen.

is there any program to get it to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the freeware [Edgeless](http://www.fxc.btinternet.co.uk/assistive.htm), downloadable [here](http://www.fxc.btinternet.co.uk/EdgelessSetup.exe) :

> This application causes the mouse
>   pointer to wrap around the screen
>   instead of stopping at the edges. It
>   can be configured to start at Windows
>   startup if required.

(never tried this one)

Comment: For mac users there is this http://mac.softpedia.com/get/System-Utilities/Wraparound.shtml

Comment: edgeless does what it says on the tin.. but aside from that... one or two minor things one runse into.. if resizing a window or moving a scroll "stripe" down, one doesn't really want the mouse cursor moving off the screen. In the former case one could flush right normally. In the latter case, normally one can move the mouse left or right a bit while doing the operation, no prob. But it's be nice if the mouse didn't move off the screen while doing that. which can happen sometimes when a window's right edge is flushed right.